# Create password textfield in titanium

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I created a password textfield in titanium as follow but it only work in Iphone but in Android it not work.How must i do?

```
var textfield_password=Ti.UI.createTextField({
top:290,
left:50,
right:50,
hintText:'Enter your password',
passwordMask:true,
```

})

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed :
[https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-608?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-608?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

Your code also give correct output on my PC. I am using titanium sdk 2.0 with android 2.3.3